# Hot pre-compiled JSP reloading

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, tomcat8

We currently deploy our JSPs outside of the WAR. This allows us to deploy the main application container and the JSP views at different pace (one team moves much faster than the other). In order to support this, we have JSPs out of the war. When the webapp is deployed some soft-links are created to the folders the JSPs are. Finally, when we deploy new/updated JSPs, the JspServlet detects it, recompiles the new/updated JSPs and replaces the classes.

This workflow works fine when the changes are little and the servers load average is low. The problem comes when a developer modifies one of the main JSPs or the load of the servers is high. In this situation, all the servers starts to compile the updated JSP and, due to the amount of load, lots of request end up throwing 504 errors.

We are considering to pre-compile the JSPs before deploying them to the server. The problem is that we are not able to find any option to force Tomcat to hot reload ONLY the updated classes. All the different reload options that we have tested end up reloading all the webapp (which means 80s of downtime for us).

Is there any recommended option to manage this? Does somebody have a similar scenario or a suitable solution?

Many thanks in advance,

Tomàs